# Drupal module node type creation .install vs .module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

After browsing the net for over an hour my question remains.
What is the 'correct' way to create a node type in a module.

.install:
hook_install() gives you the possibility to create node_types using the node_type_save() hook...

.module
using hook_node_info() you can add node type(s).

What are the pro's and cons of those 2 methods? Is there in fact a different? What happens when you uninstall the module? How should one manage updates in both cases?
The drupal docu hasn't been really helpfull for me :(

Comment: The best way is to use hook_node_info. You can find more documentation on http://api.drupal.org. There is no other way!

Comment: there is another way. using: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_save/7

Comment: Its saving a node, you need to define the type first! If not type defined how would you relate a node to non-existent type? Did you read this: type: A string giving the machine name of the node type. If you think it works without defining the node type first, why don't you give it a try? Also check the 'code' on that page!

Comment: @JoshiConsultancy http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/625/create-new-content-type-on-hook-install

Comment: you can create it in both. Drupal Core book module creates it in hook_install. But its more common practice to do so in hook_node_info().

Comment: @D34dman but is there a difference?

Comment: if you implement using hook_node_info() you are more complaint with the way drupal works. For example node_type_rebuild() will only work with hook_node_info() and not node_type_save()

Comment: @D34dman Post that as answer so I can give you credit ;) That kind of sums up everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create node_types using both `node_type_save()` and `hook_node_info()`.

Drupal Core book module creates it in hook_install. But its more common practice to do so in hook_node_info() or hook_entity_info() ( node module uses hook_entity_info() ).

if you implement using [hook_node_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_info/7) you are more complaint with the way drupal works. For example node_type_rebuild() will only work with values defined in `hook_node_info()` and not `node_type_save()`.

Imo you should be using [hook_node_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_info/7) or [hook_entity_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info/7) and let drupal core handle the rest.

Comment: didn't know node_type_rebuild only worked with _node_info() types

Comment: @Pinoniq It doesn't, that statement is wrong - `node_types_build()` will build data for **all** node types, not just those defined in `hook_node_info()`. If you need proof just inspect the code and output of [`_node_types_build`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/_node_types_build/7). It clearly queries the `node_type` table for content types that are not defined in `hook_node_info()`. There's no question of being _'more compliant with the way Drupal works'_ by using `hook_node_info()`, that just isn't true

Comment: @D34dman Do you have a source for any of these assertions? (_its more common practice to do so in hook_node_info()_, _you are more complaint with the way drupal works_)? I've been developing in Drupal for a few years now, and I've never read or heard anything remotely like that

Comment: with all due respect @Clive, if you check the function you just mentioned it queries the database and not the function that was used to create node_type_save(). So if a user had changed the value of a node type through admin, node_type_rebuild would be able to reset to default only if its declared using hook_node_info().

Comment: @D34dman My bad, I misunderstood the point you were making. Apologies